# IE7 Compatibility mode in Ie10 not working

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-7, meta

Thanks in advnace for the help.

We are using bootstrap 3, HTML5 with PHP-AngularJs, and facing some issues.

- When I open the browser in IE10 with Compatibility mode IE7, the site not showing anything.

Please suggest what maybe the problem. I already used everything as per the google and other suggestions like header, meta tags, css etc.

(I already used multiple meta-tags like:

- meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"
- meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"
- meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"

Answer (score 0):

Check this [article](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

1. Add link to JSON for IE lt 8th.
2. Don't use custom tags, use attributes instead. But if it is
   necessary, they have to be declared in the header.
3. If you use cross domain requests via Angularjs they should be
   changed to JSONP, because angularjs uses CORS that not supported by
   our favorite browser IE8 and less.

But the best answer, do not support IE7 :) you will save much nerves

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try for it and get back to you.. :)

Comment: Its not working, because default with IE10 its showing IE7 compatibility document mode, and site is not showing anything. Help needed.